# ListView - Align vertical grid lines with Headers dividers - Make last Column fill the space

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to write a Windows Forms MusicPlayer application in C#.

The application should show a list and have some play / stop buttons.

I just started half an hour ago, but my design is almost finished. Now I got 3 things to fix. A bug and 2 good looking things:

1. on the picture you can see the bug I've found. You might say that's nothing, but its a eye catcher. How can I fix this?

   [image: -]
2. how can I align center the headline of a column, without centering the content?
3. how can I make the last column filling out the rest of the listView?

Comment: You are using a list view or a DataGridView?

Comment: listView with details enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can set the `TextAlign` of all but the 1st Column's Header; it is always left aligned. To change that you need to owner draw it.
- There is no automatic filling option so you need to write a `setColumnwidth` function, that loops over all but the last columns and sums their `Widths`; then it subtract the sum from the ListView's `Clientsize.Width` and set the last column's Width.
- The display bug in the gridlines is new to me; so far I don't know how to fix it; maybe owner-drawing will help there as well..?

**Update:**

Here is some code:

```
void setLastColumnTofill(ListView lv)
{
     int sum = 0;
     int count  = lv.Columns.Count;
     for (int i = 0; i < count   - 1; i++) sum += lv.Columns[i].Width;
     lv.Columns[count   - 1].Width = lv.ClientSize.Width - sum;
}
```

After setting `OwnerDraw = true` you could code the three (all are needed!) Draw event :

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Menu, e.Bounds);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(SystemPens.GradientInactiveCaption, 
        new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X , 0, e.Bounds.Width , e.Bounds.Height) );

    string text = listView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Text;
    TextFormatFlags cFlag = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter 
                          | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, listView1.Font, e.Bounds, Color.Black, cFlag);
}

private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}

private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

You may want to play a little with the colors or the widths..

If you have an ImageList containing images for displaying the sort order (or other things) you can add this to draw them as well:

```
 ColumnHeader colH = listView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
 int ii = colH.ImageIndex;
 if (ii >= 0 && ii < imageList1.Images.Count) 
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[ii], 
              e.Bounds.Width + e.Bounds.X - imageList1.ImageSize.Width, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: its working :) (I was to lazy to ownerdraw all this stuff, but the automatic filling thing was most important) Thanks!

Comment: I have added the code for filling and for owner-drawing :-)

Comment: Complete answer. I recommend using `VisualStyleRenderer` to gain better look and feel. I would be happy if you kindly take a look at my post and find it useful :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, in this case it indeed does a great job! +1! Note that you should use the LV's ClientSize.Width in your column width routine. I put it in a function to allow calling it later, when things may have changed..

Comment: @TaW I know this is a long time ago solution. I have the same issue and the exact solution I am looking at. It works! Except that my text is duplicating at runtime. One is the original which is located in the top vertical alignment and the correct one is at the center vertically. I am looking at your `Draw Event` code and haven't changed anything, copied it entirely but why I am getting the duplicate header text? I hope at least you give me a clue... thanks.

Comment: Hm, hard to tell. The listView1_DrawColumnHeader event starts with a FillRectangle that ought to clear/cover the original text, even if it happend. You didn't put an extra e.DrawDefault = true there, right?

Answer (score 4):

After setting `OwnerDraw` to `true` you can do other stuff like this:

**Draw ListView**

```
int sortIndex = 0;
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender,
   DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    var state = e.State == ListViewItemStates.Selected ?
        VisualStyleElement.Header.Item.Hot : VisualStyleElement.Header.Item.Normal;
    var sortOrder = listView1.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending ?
        VisualStyleElement.Header.SortArrow.SortedUp :
        VisualStyleElement.Header.SortArrow.SortedDown;
    var itemRenderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(state);
    var sortRenderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(sortOrder);
    var r = e.Bounds; 
    r.X += 1;
    itemRenderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, r);
    r.Inflate(-2, 0);
    var flags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter |
        TextFormatFlags.SingleLine;
    itemRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, r, e.Header.Text, false, flags);
    var d = SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
    if (e.ColumnIndex == sortIndex) //Sorted Column
        sortRenderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, 
            new Rectangle(r.Right - d, r.Top, d, r.Height));
}

private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;  /*Use default rendering*/
}

private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;  /*Use default rendering*/
}
```

**Fill ListView using Last Column**

```
private void ListViewSample_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var otherItemWisth= this.listView1.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>()
        .Where(x => x.Index < this.listView1.Columns.Count - 1)
        .Sum(x => x.Width);
    this.listView1.Columns[this.listView1.Columns.Count - 1].Width = 
        this.listView1.ClientSize.Width - otherItemWisth;
}
```

**Result**

[image]