# ListView Columns/GridlinesOffset/Alignment error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, gridlines

Why is there an offset between the gridlines and the columns and how would I fix it? Ive tried adding listview outside and inside a groupbox and adding 10 items to it without being able to fix it..

I am using winforms

[image: Columns/Gridlines offset]

Cheers

Comment: You should make the control owner-draw. Take a look at this post:[Align the ListView vertical grid lines with Column Headers dividers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424074/windows-forms-fix-the-listview-items).