# WinForms ListView Details Column Rendering Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a simple WinForms ListView that is set to display in Details view with a few items.

Maybe this is a well-known issue with an easy fix but I can't seem to get this to look right:

[image: Zoomed-in screenshot of the ListView (click to embiggen)]

The column gridlines are slightly off.

Here's the relevant code:

```cs
partial class MainForm
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.listView = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // listView
        // 
        this.listView.FullRowSelect = true;
        this.listView.GridLines = true;
        this.listView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.listView.MultiSelect = false;
        this.listView.Name = "listView";
        this.listView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(539, 150);
        this.listView.TabIndex = 0;
        this.listView.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.listView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(564, 185);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listView);
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.Text = "Main Form";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView;
}
```

Has anyone seen this? I haven't used the ListView control before but I have noted more than a few problems with it here on the Internet. I haven't yet found anything specifically about this problem, though.

NOTE: Unfortunately, I cannot use any third-party controls as a solution to this, only stock-standard WinForms.

Comment: This is a known bug, as far as I remember. Not sure if it is worth [owner-drawing the control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424074/listview-align-vertical-grid-lines-with-headers-dividers-make-last-column-fi)..

Comment: @TaW Owner-drawing fixes the alignment, thanks! However, the sorting images I have aren't being shown on the `listView_ColumnClick()` event. Code is similar to this: `listView.Columns["Name"].ImageKey = SortDirection.Ascending;` (yes, `listView.LargeImageList` and `listView.SmallImageList` have been set correctly). I guess I should be using something other than `visualStyleRenderer.DrawText()` in the `listView_DrawColumnHeader()` event handler? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the other answer with a few lines to include the images. Try to see if it is useful for you..

Comment: To get a better result when rendering, you can use `VisualStyleRenderer`. I used it to draw `ColumnHeader` in the linked answer. Aslo you can use it to draw the sort glyph. For example `var sortRenderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Header.SortArrow.SortedDown);` and draw the glyph the same as the column header is drawn in the linked post.

Comment: @SameerSingh I edited the answer in linked post to contain also rendering of sort glyph and closed the question as exact duplicate.

Comment: By the way @SameerSingh If you found the linked post useful, it would be great if you vote for question and answer to make them more popular and more useful for future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use DatagridView control for multiple column, else look this link http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-listview.htm ;)